# Changing the function of the change of variables

Tags: java

How do I change the `event.getPlayer().getEquipment().getHelmet().getTypeId()` on `event.getPlayer().getEquipment().getHelmet().getType()` if the `boolean variable = true`.

```
public void PickupItem(PlayerPickupItemEvent event) {
    Player p = event.getPlayer();
    if (UraniumProtectMain.blocked.contains(event.getItem().getItemStack().getTypeId())) {
        if (p.getEquipment().getHelmet() != null && p.getEquipment().getHelmet().getTypeId() == 123) {
            event.setCancelled(false);
        } else {
            event.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's hard to me to understand what are you even asking, but... `getHelmet().setTypeId(...)` ?

Comment: You can not change the code or the written function on run time. But you could simply add the desired function call in the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that you are trying to change type ID boolean event.getItem().getItemStack().getTypeId() to get Type object by event.getPlayer().getEquipment().getHelmet().getType().

as i thought you trying to get type object by type ID then you can just check if type object is not equal to null that will solve your problem.